# Wi-Fi connectivity issues after installing Cisco 64-bit VPN client on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cisco-vpn-client, wireless-networking

How do I completely restore Wi-Fi settings and drivers back to Windows defaults? I installed an old Cisco VPN client (5.0.07.0290). It completely hosed up the machine I was working on. Once I figured out the issue was with the client, I fixed the issue on two other machines by restoring them back to before I installed the client. However on this machine for some reason there are no restore points prior to the installation.

I have uninstalled the client, but I'm still having the network connectivity problem.

My best description of the problem is this: when you connect to a wireless access point, Windows then reports "limited connectivity" on Wi-Fi. Rebooting, reinstalling TCP/IP, deleting the settings and readding, rebooting the WAP and then the computer do not work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already uninstalled the Cisco VPN driver and ran the removal tools provided by Cisco for such situations plus deleted all VPN adapters from your device manager (with "show disabled devices" turned on in it).

Try deleting the network device from the device manager, disable automatic driver installation, reboot, run device manager, search for new devices, find the network adapter, pick the driver manually to make sure it doesn't use relicts of the Cisco driver, install it. Pray.

Comment: Ok masi, thank you for responding.

The part I don't know about is the removal tools you mention.  Where can I find those?  

Also, how do I disable automatic driver installation?

Thanks again for your help.  This is by far the most hosed I've ever seen the internet configuration on a computer.

Comment: is this what you're referring to? http://www.howtonetworking.com/cisco/ciscovpnclient1.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can try this link and hotfix supplied by microsoft to reset your network stack:
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357?wa=wsignin1.0

Also, when installing vpn clients watch out for "management devices" that override the default (windows) wifi/ethernet adapter management interfaces with their own proprietary stuff -- which will definitely cause issues.

I know the cisco anyconnect client's still do this, as we deal with this all the time when our helpdesk tech accidentally installs the entire package without excluding the interface management software.

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be worked around by disabling Cisco's network access manager service. This lets the Windows native WIFI driver to be used instead of Cisco's one. See [WiFi issues with Cisco AnyConnect](http://www.technlg.net/windows/wifi-issues-with-cisco-anyconnect/)

Comment: Please mention the key parts of the linked page in case the link dies in the future. Thanks!